# Excel Formula - Column SUM where two columns match values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a table where I need to obtain the sum of one column where the values in two other columns match specific criteria.

[image]

What I need would be the sum of the Value column where the customer name matches Customer A and the Order Status matches Complete. For this example the result would be £150.00

I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: consider about [SUMIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx)

Comment: I managed to get a count using COUNTIFS but I haven't been able to work out the SUM part hence asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS is available in 2007+

first parameter is what values to sum, the subsuiquent pairs are the range and their criteria.

For your example, it would be

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,"Customer A",C:C,"Completed")
```

You could also summarize the whole table using a pivot table.